# Creating a general file path

Tags: r, path

I'd like to create a general file path to share my code others. I saw that there is a function `file.path()` but I can't figure out how to use it.

For example if I have the following in my R script, how should change it so it is easier for others to open it on their computers?

```
df <- read.cvs("/Users/myname/Downloads/data.csv")
```

I've tried using the [`here()` package](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) per suggested in the comment below but I don't think I'm doing it properly. Here is the result:  `here("data", "data.csv")`
This error appeared:

> cannot open file '/Users/myname/Downloads/data.csv': No such file or directory

I also tried `read_csv(here("data.csv"))` and the following error appeared:

> Error: '/Users/myname/Downloads/data.csv' does not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Comment: Thank you for sharing but it is not working for me unfortunately. I am putting the results as an update above.

Comment: How about using RStudio Projects? That way you only have relative paths. Meaning you don't need to explicit your username. That's a very hand way of working on a project with a team. I am not sure this is your final goal though

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti Thanks for the suggestion.  I have to share the file with my supervisor so unfortunately I cannot use the Rstudio projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using `sprintf` in such cases.

```
wd <- "/home/jay"  ## replace with your working directory

read.csv(sprintf('%s/data.csv', wd))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
write.csv(matrix(1:12, 3, 4), 'data.csv', row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, This command works but to clarify, am I to ask my supervisor to assign their directory to 'wd' and then plug in into the above?

Comment: @bear_525 Yes, the idea is, they only have to specify their working directory once at the beginning of the script.